# Problem with Cividiscount and pricesets

Tags: cividiscount, price-sets

When setting up a cividiscount coupon, it doesn't work on events where a price set is used.  If I set up the fee directly on the events page then the discount shows up but not on events where price sets are used.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Alex - what versions of Civi and the discount extension are you using, please?

Comment: I am using crm 4.6.3 and  discount version 2.6  I tried to update the discount but am getting an error that the files can't extract and also this error

Comment: "The downloader may be unable to download files which require HTTP redirection. This may be a configuration issue with PHP's open_basedir or safe_mode."

Comment: Just upgraded the discount extension and still the discount coupon codes are not being applied to events fee's with a price set.

Comment: cividiscount 2.6 is supposedly compatible up to crm 4.4 (check info.xml in your cividiscount folder). You could download later cividiscount (3.0/3.1) which is compatible w/crm 4.6. Disable and de-install your 2.6 cividiscount and upload/install the newer one afresh.  After install, when you go to create a discount code you should see the priceset values which are linked to your events to filter on. (u  can use older cividiscount tables, I think no schema changes were involved)

Answer (score 1):

Can you post a screenshot of your discount settings? You must make sure that you created a price set for the event (sounds like you did) and that you added the price set as an option for the code to work with in the coupon settings.